# How to create a connection to the node where queue is created in, RabbitMQ

Tags: java, rabbitmq

We will have a a clusters, say 3 nodes, now we will pass three addresses to create a connection:

```
factory.newConnection(consumerExecutor, addresses, clinetProviedName);// addresses has three elements
```

Questions:

```
1 .Since a queue is created in only one node which is master say nodeA. So if I create a connection to nodeB, does RabbitMQ need to redirect every publish requests to the nodeA from nodeB? 

2. Will the same things happen to consumers?

3. Does Redirect makes a big difference on performance when qps is high? We need tens of thousands qps to support our app.

4. If #1 is right, how can I connect to the exactly right node to reduce redirect.
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes
2. Yes
3. No, but your benchmarks and monitoring will definitively answer it. You do have benchmarks and monitoring, right?
4. It isn't worth the hassle. The Spring AMQP library does have a node affinity feature if you really think it's worth it.